# Statistical tests for comparing (black box) model performance on two datasets

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, model-evaluation, method-comparison

**Introduction**

I have two datasets, dataA (real images) and dataB (generated images). I also have a model that has been trained on dataC. dataC might have some overlap with dataA but for certain does not have any overlap with dataB. The model is a black box to me (in fact, it sits behind an API), I know nothing about it or about its training dataset and procedure, I only receive the model outputs.

I want to know if the model "behaves" the same way on dataA as on dataB, i.e. test the hypothesis that the distribution of dataB is similar to the distribution of dataA (with respect to the task performed by the model).

**Regression model**

If the model is a regression model, e.g. detects some landmarks in the image, I can calculate some real-numbered error, e.g. the euclidean distance between the actual landmark position and the one predicted by the model. Applying the model to dataA as well as dataB gives me two collections of errors: errorsA and errorsB. The errors are not necessarily normal distributed (depends on the model I am testing).

Which statistical tests can I use to compare errorsA and errorsB? I have considered:

- Calculating confidence intervals on errorsA and errorsB, respectively and check if they overlap.
- Use a statistical test to check the hypothesis that errorsA and errorsB follow the same distribution. I have been using [a two-sided KS test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).

**Classification model**

Same question, but now I do not have errors, but instead some metric such as accuracy or F1. Use Chi-Square test as proposed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162510/comparing-performance-of-a-single-classifier-on-two-datasets)?

Comment: How about a paired t-test?

Comment: paired t-test would be for the regression model, right? @user2974951 Or can I also use it for the classification model? Also, it seems to me that I can not use this if errorA and errorB are not normal distributed.

Comment: A paired t test compares the means of two dependent samples and requires normally distributed residuals, not the data itself.

Comment: @user2974951 The residuals are not normally distributed. Is there anything else I can do in that situation? Thanks for your quick answers, btw!

Comment: In that case you can use the non-parametric version of the paired t-test: Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

Comment: @user2974951 Interesting! But I fear that assumption 1 "Data are paired and come from the same population." from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test](this page) does not hold for my situation.  My data is not paired. dataA is random images from the internet, dataB is random images picked from the images generated by a generative model. There is nothing connecting the first image of dataA with the first image of dataB.

Comment: But I just found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test, which is an unpaired version. This seems to be what I am looking for!

Comment: I must have misunderstood when I first read your question. Mann Whitney is the non-paired version. How many predictions are you making anyway?

Comment: I have made 200 predictions each, for dataA and dataB. I can increase that, if necessary, its just a matter of creating more ground truth data (i.e. annotating images with the real landmarks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you have access only to the model output (predictions, or rather errors), and you want to compare these for two different data sets A and B to check if they return similar results. The question now is what do you want to compare. If a mean is enough - that is comparing whether the two data sets return the same mean error - then a t-test could be used.

If the *residuals* from the t-test are not normally distributed then a non-parametric version can be used such as Mann-Whitney, which has no assumptions on the distribution, but also doesn't compare the means. The null hypothesis is that the distributions of both populations are equal.

However, if you plan to make a lot of predictions, then such tests will be mostly useless (difference between statistical and practical significance) and you may as well just use a standard predictive metric to compare the differences in model performance, such as accuracy, F1,... or a proper scoring rule if you want to be correct, such as logarithmic scoring rule.